# Polymorphism/Resource loader with Zend

Tags: php, polymorphism, zend-form

I've never worked before with polymorphism. I just heard about it when this question came up.

I have a little backend with 2 permissions. Admin/Normal User. Depending on the permission, i want to display a different navigation, less or more options on the forms etc. But i don't want to create a form for each permission but rather disable the elements i don't need etc.

How would i go with that?

At the moment, i'm using something like that: (Which isn't really polymorphism)

```
<?php

class My_Resources_ResourceLoader extends Zend_Application_Resource_ResourceAbstract {
    public $templateForm = null;
    public $customerForm = null;

    function init() {
        $permission = 'admind';
        if($permission == 'admin') {
            $this->templateForm = new Application_Form_newTemplate;
        } else {
            $form = new Application_Form_newTemplate;
            $form->removeElement('newTemplate_customer');
            $this->templateForm = $form;
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

And in my controller e.g.

```
<?php

$bootstrap = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap');
$xx = $bootstrap->getResource('ResourceLoader');
$this->view->test = $xx->templateForm;
```

The roles never gonna change. This will probably be okay but isn't the very best solution. What would be a better approach to this?

Answer (score 1):

I've thrown away the approach above and now use real polymorphism like this:

at Application/Model got an interface like:

And 2 Classes like:

```
<?php

class Application_Model_TemplateUser implements Application_Model_TemplateInterface {
    private $table = null;
    private $row = null;
    private $id = null;
    private $formValues = null;

    function __construct() {}
    public function exist() {}
    public function save() {}   
    public function getCustomerId($name) {}
    public function update() {}
    public function getForm() {
        $form = new Application_Form_newTemplate;
        $form->removeElement('newTemplate_customer');
        return $form;
    }
}
```

And

```
<?php

class Application_Model_TemplateAdmin implements Application_Model_TemplateInterface {
    private $table = null;
    private $row = null;
    private $id = null;
    private $formValues = null;


    function __construct() {}
    public function exist() {}
    public function save() {}
    public function getCustomerId($name) {}
    public function update() {}

    public function getForm() {
        return new Application_Form_NewTemplate();
    }
}
```

In my Controller i do:

```
<?php
        $permission = 'User'; //TODO: Get from Session
        $class = 'Application_Model_Template' . $permission;
        $xx = new $class;
        $form = $xx->getForm();
        $this->view->test = $form;
```

This are just examples. But i think like that I'm really on a better way. Maybe i'm going to use abstract classes since i'm using Zend_Db-Table_Row, which is always the same for updating a row, so it would make more sense using a abstract class instead of an interface.

Nice article about Polymorphism in PHP: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/understanding-and-applying-polymorphism-in-php/